# Can I set a default Window size in OSX or snap to notification pane? (Because of broken screen)

Tags: macos, osx-el-capitan

Because of [this](https://twitter.com/SystemsInCode/status/736160199296339973) I can't really see the notification area/pane anymore. I want to be able to set a default window size for all windows, is this possible? If app windows went up to the notification pane area it would be great. For example if I could set the pane to not overlay on top of existing windows, but share the screen I could just leave it on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'SizeUp' app from [irradiatedsoftware](http://www.irradiatedsoftware.com/) helps me resize any window to avoid the damaged screen area using the 'margins' feature. (I could do this manually of course but it's a pain).

Now when I start an problem window I just set it smaller and then 'maximise' from the menu icon and it fills the available space.

It also has nice left/right snapping functionality like Windows has with Windows-Key + '<-' / '->' which is great.